# Mouseover events of two DIVs, positioned one over the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to trigger the mouseover event of two DIVs positioned one on top of other.

http://jsfiddle.net/hvh8k/

For the DIV in front, if I have given `pointer-events:none;` I will get the mouseover event of the DIV underneath. But this stops triggering the mouseover event of the DIV in front.

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    var stopAnimation = false;
    var loop1 = setInterval(function () {
        if(stopAnimation)return;
        var L = parseInt($("#back").css("left"), 10) + 10;
        if(L > $(window).width())L=-300;
        $("#back").css("left", L);
    }, 100);
    $("#back").mouseover(function () {
        stopAnimation = true;
    });
    $("#back").mouseout(function () {
        stopAnimation = false;
    });
    $("#front").mouseover(function () {
        $("#front").animate({width:200}, 100);
    });
    $("#front").mouseout(function () {
        $("#front").animate({width:100}, 100);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#back {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#front {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #caa;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="back"></div>
    <div id="front"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mouseover events of two DIVs, positioned one on top of the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678036/mouseover-events-of-two-divs-positioned-one-on-top-of-the-other)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would be suited for what you are trying to achieve, but what about toggling the `z-index` as you click the divs?

First `div.front` will show. When `div.front` is clicked, it calls your function AND move `div.front` to the back, and `div.back` to the front, which would allow you to click and trigger the `div.back` function and toggle the divs again.

So to be clear... front visible > click > back visible > click > front visible etc.